# Partial classes in different namespace are not being recognized correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, partial-classes

I have a partial class that is split over two namespaces. The problem is that if I have an interface implemented on one of the partials, it is not recognized on the counterpart partial class. For example, I would expect the below to return true for being recognized as `ILastModified` (C# fiddle at http://ideone.com/heLDn0):

```
using System;
using MyNamespace.One;
 
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var item = new Product();
        Console.WriteLine(item is ILastModified); //RETURNS FALSE??!
    }
}
 
interface ILastModified
{
    DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}
 
namespace MyNamespace.One
{
    public partial class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
 
namespace MyNamespace.Two
{
    public partial class Product : ILastModified
    {
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If they're in different namespaces, then they're not part of the same class.  A class' namespace is part of its identity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot have a partial class in two different namespaces. The compiler treats those as two different classes.

Comment: Each class has a fully qualified name which consists of the namespace and the class name.

Answer (score 9):

> I have a partial that is split over two namespaces.

You can't. By being in different namespaces, they are different classes.

Consider that this is the reason namespaces exist - so you can have the same class *name* for different classes.

From the C# Language Specification (C# 4.0), §10.2, Partial types:

> Each part of a partial type declaration must include a partial modifier. It must have the same name **and be declared in the same namespace** or type declaration as the other parts.

(emphasis mine)

So, by definition, what you are doing is not a partial type.

Answer (score 2):

See [Partial Class Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> Using the partial keyword indicates that other parts of the class, struct, or interface can be defined within **the** namespace.

This is due to the fact that partial types must be within the same namespace because each class has a fully quantified name which includes the namespace. A prime example of this is with Windows Forms Application the designer and the UI code are seperated using  a partial class. It also prevents bad design in my opinion!

You can see this for yourself using simple reflection code (for fun mostly).

```
var namespaces = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                         .Select(t => t.Namespace)
                         .Distinct();

//Returns:
//  WindowsFormsApplication2
//  WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces provide logical seperation of Types.  `MyNamespace.One.Product` and `MyNamespace.Two.Product` are two different types (if this were not the case, then there would be no point in having Namespaces in the first place!)

Because of `using MyNamespace.One;`,

In `Main()`:

`var item = new Product();`

is the equivalent of:

`var item = new MyNamespace.One.Product()`

Change the namespace of the second `Product` type to `MyNamespace.One`