# How to create partial class instance from original

Tags: c#, .net, oop, partial

I have class A in namespace `do.it.like.a.boss`,

After that I am creating another class A that it will be partial and the namespace will `be do.it.like.a.child`

Until now everything sounds good ... **but**

I have prop that I want to return the partial class and the actual data in my list is the original one

```
public do.it.like.a.child.A A
{
   get
   {
      return my list.Where(x => x.id == someid).FirstOrDeffult(); // the list is do.it.like.a.boss.A objects
   }
}
```

Is it even possible to do something in that case ?

Thanks

Comment: As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4504306/9363973) answer states, you cannot have two parts of a class in two different namespaces. do.it.like.a.boss.A and do.it.like.a.child.A are two entirely different types that just happen to share a name

Comment: Can you show more code? It is very hard to ascertain what you are trying to do. A partial class must have all "fragments" in the same namespace.

Comment: What is even the purpose of your idea (spreading partial classes over namespaces)?

Comment: You cannot have a partial class in two namespaces. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446250/1273882

Comment: @Ackdari , reverse engineering thought maybe there are some new features to deal with that kind of situation

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible, because each part of a partial class needs to be in the same namespace. Take this as an example:

```cs
namespace Test.Foo
{
    public partial class Bar
    {
        public string Hello => "World";
    }
}

namespace Test.Bar
{
    public partial class Bar
    {
        // This is impossible, as Test.Foo.Bar and Test.Bar.Bar are 2 entirely different classes
        public string World => Hello;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) is the MSDN documentation on partial classes.

P.S Why would you need something like this?

Comment: thought so... reverse engineering (not my code that I should add functionality) ok.. need to change list datasource, thanks